# Could someone help me to figure out the hierarchy between QTextEdit,QTextDocment,QTextBlock,QTextFrame,etc.?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

Could someone help me to figure out the relations between `QTextEdit`, `QTextDocment`, `QTextBlock`, `QTextFrame`, etc.?

I need an overview,thank you in advance.

I just want to have a thorough knowledge of `QTextEdit`. Perhaps someone want to mark me as lazy because I can figure it out by reading qt-project documents. Yes, it is right and I am doing it. But maybe it is not a trivial thing for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QTextEdit` is a widget that displays a `QTextDocument` which has one root `QTextFrame`, consists of `QTextBlock`s and can have child `QTextFrame`s.

Comment: A perfect overview.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

using MVC design pattern `QTextEdit` is a view (and partially controller) and `QTextDocment` is a model.

So `QTextDocment` is just a container for the text data and layout of text. `QTextBlock` represents a single paragraph in document. `QTextCursor` is a tool to perform any modifications in text document (model).

I recommended to read documentation it is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks you for telling me **QTextEdit** is a view.I knew MVC in Qt but I din't have a clear knowledge of the Qt's MVC hierarchy.I also think Qt's official documents are pretty good.I have lots to do.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to give `QTextFrame` or `QTextBlock` a background image? I wan to show texts on a specified image in `QTextEdit`.